# Deploy meteor 8.3 and higher on openshift

Tags: node.js, meteor, openshift

My question is simple, does anyone know how to make a meteor app running version 8.3 and higher on openshift server.

I tried following the tutorial provided from Openshift: https://github.com/openshift-quickstart/openshift-meteorjs-quickstart

The issue with this, it is pretty old and meant to be run with older meteor version. The error I get from the console says that it needs node.js version 0.10.29 or higher to run.

I tried using custom solutions for custom node.js versions like this: https://github.com/vladka/openshift-meteor-leaderboard-customNode and "/ramr/nodejs-custom-version-openshift"

I also tried using some branches and other solutions like   "/questions/24316495/how-to-upgrade-node-js-in-openshift-gear" and   "/questions/20408160/meteor-on-openshift-node-version"

None of the above solutions worked for me. I tried using different deployments, I used the basic "bundle" function from meteor 8.3 version as described for openshift. It didn't work. I tried using "demeteorizer" too. On higher meteor versions I used "build" too. It didn't work. Every time it was just saying that meteor needs 0.10.29 or higher to run even though it was reported under /env path and console that it uses a custom node.js version of 0.10.29 or higher (depending on what I used).

I tried using both Linux and windows for meteor itself. Used 8.0 and all higher versions. Checked for dependencies and all related version upgrades for meteor. It runs locally just fine so there are no meteor issues on it's own. It also runs on a test server on meteor.com itself, so I doubt that it is a meteor version issue, or my specific meteor app itself.

I tried using a basic example from one of the above links with a meteor version 0.6.3 which did work because it uses an older version of node.js. Officially openshift supports and provides only node.js version 0.10.25 that's why an older version of meteor with an example app worked fine.

Comment: +1. Was in your shoes last week, asked a question here, not much help. Gave up on meteor, using "pure" node.js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have meteor v1.0.2 running successfully on Openshift. [Meteor and Famo.us on Openshift](http://famview-tutaslabs.rhcloud.com) I also followed the references mentioned by the OP. However, I had to make some mods. The important thing is that you have to use a DIY and roll your own. I took the 
vladka git (mentioned by the OP) and modified it to make it a lot simpler. Another thing to remember is that meteor has some binary node dependencies (esp. fibers) that have to get installed during the push. Overall I am very pleased and have used Openshift for a number of commercial Meteor/Famo.us web applications. I will try to post a tutorial and git when i get a chance.

[Meteor on OpenShift Tutorial](http://tutas-labs.com/meteor-on-openshift)

Comment: I would really love to see a tutorial or any sort of more in-depth explanation of how you managed to do it, that would really help me a lot and probably some more people too.

Comment: send us something on twitter when you get this put together @openshift

Comment: glad i could help. You will really enjoy working with Meteor!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately at this time meteor applications won't work on OpenShift. There are a few reasons but mainly it comes down to meteor team wants to be hosted by passenger instead of being run by node or supervisor (which is what OpenShift uses). We realize that this is something that needs to be resolved and we are actively working towards getting meteor applications working on OpenShift.